# Something isnt booting right?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Let me preface all of this by saying Im very new to Linux as a whole.

So basically, Im trying to install Linux onto one of my systems SSDs. I went through the process with someone who is better than me with Linux and they made sure I had the correct root and boot partitions set up on the drive.

However, in my BIOS, the generic name is the only thing that shows up in the boot order other than Windows. I cant get the full name to show up. Ive used the GRUB line that comes up every time to boot into my OS, and I also tried using the boot repair tool and a few other lines, such as `sudo update-grub`. It still wont appear in BIOS. What am I doing wrong?

A few things I do know:

When I installed off the USB, I installed to the drive labeled /dev/sdc.

When using GNU GRUB, my boot drive is labeled as `(hd1,1)`, and my root drive is `(hd1,2)`.

Sorry if my formatting is bad. First post.

Any and all help is very appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: What sort of Linux you are trying to install?

Comment: pop OS. The guy who I got the distribution from claims its based on “Gnome”. Im using a variant based on a content creator I like that focuses on gaming optimizations.

Comment: Pop OS is off-topic,